# Kubectl keep asking username / password when interacting with EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm following the [Getting Started with Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) tutorial. Everything goes well until the **Step 2: Create a kubeconfig File** when I have to test my configuration with a `$ kubectl get svc`.

I am always aked to give a username / password. No matter what I'm typing the EKS cluster is replying this:

```
$ kubectl get svc
Please enter Username: foo
Please enter Password: ***
Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "default
```

Does anyone ever have this problem during the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the great means:

- uninstall / install *awscli*
- uninstall / install *kubectl*

And now it works as expected.